# create a C++ problemMatcher for a single log file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-problem-matcher

I am trying to create a problemMatcher for the Keil compiler. This does not generate any console output. All output goes to a log file. I noticed that there is a npm module called Gulp that should be able to help with that. I have created a regexp that works with the output. How do I create a problemMatcher that monitors a single log file for errors and can open the source files?

Another issue is that the log file to be monitored is not in the same directory as the source code.

Another issue is that the file output does not contain any path information. There are multiple possible paths that need to be searched to find the file.

Answer (score 0):

***This is not the perfect solution for this problem but a hack and a workaround***

A few years ago I solved a similar problem, I was setting up a non-standard build in Jenkins and wanted it's diagnostics tools to parse the build logs, which was not printed to stdout. The hack was simply to add a `cat logfile` at the end of my build sequence and then the tool parsed the errors.

I think you could achieve the same for `problemMatchers` in vscode with a `cat` at the end of your build.